# What is the role of calcium in the enamel heremineralization process?

Tags: dentistry

From a very brief reading of Wikipedia, I can understand that:

1. Enamel is made up mostly of Hydroxyapatite Ca10(PO4)6(OH)2, which in the process of demineralization undergoes some chemical transformation. This process requires an acidic environment.
2. When the environment is no longer acidic, the enamel can absorb fluoride from the environment forming Fluorapatite Ca5(PO4)3F.

From that, I can see that what happened is that the OH group got replaced with fluoride.

This makes perfect sense to me.

But there is an article on Wikipedia saying that

> Remineralization occurs on a daily basis after attack by acids from food, through the presence of calcium, phosphate and fluoride found in saliva. Saliva also acts as a natural buffer to neutralize acid, preventing demineralization in the first place. If there is reduced saliva flow or reduced saliva quality, this will increase the risk of demineralization and create the need for treatment in order to prevent demineralization progression.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remineralisation_of_teeth#cite_note-9

I don't really see how the presence of calcium and phosphate can help to remineralize the teeth. Can you explain it to me?

The Wikipedia article references some papers and I read some of them but I can not make any sense of them.